# The file name does not save to database

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I have a form for inserting new article .my problem is in saving the full path of picture to database.The picture is successfully uploaded to a folder and I can get the path of picture without its name and extension.can you tell me what is wrong with my code?
Thanks.
I take the upload path with this function:

```
$path=dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/upload';
$data=array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
$upload_path=$path.$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
```

when I echo the

```
echo $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
```

it shows nothing.

Comment: How did you save the path in the database, did you save it at all ? What is in `$upload_path` ?

Comment: yes I save the `$upload_path` in database.I mean the full path

Comment: Then what query result gives you ?

Comment: Also, check `$data` by `var_dump($data)` and make sure it contains all upload info ?

Comment: it is just the path of folder without name of file

Comment: Make sure `$data` contains everything as expected by `var_dump($data)`.

Comment: `var_dump($data)` just returns the `['file_path']` and `['full_path']` with the same length of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use this way to save the full path of uploaded image to database:

```
$path=dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])."/upload/".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
```

now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one mistake in your code and it is:

```
$path=dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/upload'; // <-- No ending slash
$data=array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
$upload_path=$path.$data['upload_data']['file_name']; // <-- No slash added here
```

So, you should separate the directory name and file name using a slash when concatenating  like:

```
$upload_path = $path .'/'. $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
```

Also, you may just use:

```
$path = '...';
$data = $this->upload->data();
$upload_path = $path . '/' . $data['file_name'];
```

Make sure `$data = $this->upload->data(); var_dump($data)` contains something like this:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

Comment: I tried this but when I echo `$data['file_name']` an error was shown which undefined index:file_name .the problem is with file_name I tried to echo `$data['upload_data']['file_name']` it did not show any thing

Comment: in `var_dump()` all indexes contain 0 excepting `[file_path]` and `[full_path] `.I do not know what is wrong